# Remove white space at Chapterpage

Tags: spacing, chapters, scrreprt

i have an issue with the white space at my chapter page.
[image]

This white space is way too big, however i have a header on every page like so:
[image]

Is there a way to remove the white space (because there is no header on the chapter page)?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headsepline]{scrreprt}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0cm,
afterskip=0.5cm]{chapter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[3-7]
\chapter{State of Knowledge}
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This MWE won't compile without supplying a title or commenting out `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of a negative value for `beforeskip` with the declaration of `afterindent` as either `true` or `false` will reduce the white space above the chapter heading. E.g. `\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterindent=false, beforeskip=-6\baselineskip, afterskip=0.5cm]{chapter}`

Comment: wow thanks alot! thats does the job :)

Comment: Yes, it does the job; I have no idea, though, if that is an advisable solution or if it produces unwanted side effects.

Comment: so far everything is perfect- using it in my main file which is around 100 pages and it seems to work just fine. 

but funny enough- i treid it with beforeskip=-minusvalues but it messed everything up somehow. 
Thanks alot for your response. you're helping alot of ppl now :)